# Talend - Not possible to run jobs - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hive, talend

I am using Talend v6.0.1 with java jdk 1.8u65 for jobs that involve mySQL and Hive.
Jobs that use mySQL functionnalities work just fine, thre ones using Hive on the other end always crash in a really strange way.

Here is how it goes:

- I open Talend, run a job using Hive, it works:

  ```
  Démarrage du job InsertCustomers_Into_Hive a 16:39 13/11/2015.
  [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3543
  [statistics] connected
   START JOB TO LOAD PROJECT CONTEXT C:\webs\project
  ContextReader_PROJECT: context will be loaded from C:\webs\project/project-batch.properties
  ...
  ```
- I run it again, it does not work anymore:

  ```
  Démarrage du job InsertCustomers_Into_Hive a 16:40 13/11/2015.
  [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3881
  [statistics] connected
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: project_batch_talend/contextreader_project_1_0/ContextReader_PROJECT
      at project_batch_talend.insertcustomers_into_hive_0_1.InsertCustomers_Into_Hive.tRunJob_1Process(InsertCustomers_Into_Hive.java:2382)
      at project_batch_talend.insertcustomers_into_hive_0_1.InsertCustomers_Into_Hive.runJobInTOS(InsertCustomers_Into_Hive.java:4981)
      at project_batch_talend.insertcustomers_into_hive_0_1.InsertCustomers_Into_Hive.main(InsertCustomers_Into_Hive.java:4622)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project_batch_talend.contextreader_project_1_0.ContextReader_PROJECT
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      ... 3 more
  [statistics] disconnected
  Job InsertCustomers_Into_Hive terminé à 16:40 13/11/2015. [Code sortie=1]
  ```
- If I run any other job (including mySQL jobs that usually don't give me any trouble) I get the same error.

I tried installing the same environnement on another machine, I get the same error.

I hope you can give me an idea to solve this.
Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this question. If this happens to you, it is probably because you are reusing jobs from someone else.

[Parameters of tHiveConnection_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgwqX.png)

Go to the parameters of your tHiveConnection_1 component, click on the button left of distribution choice, delete all libraries. After that you will be asked to reload them. Pick a distribution and different versions until it works.

Cheers,

Alex